# woocommerce product sort order change by our own weight value or menu order

Tags: sorting, woocommerce, product

I need to add a specified value or weight for a product so that product will display as per order on the woocommerce shop page. I think this can be done by product bulk edit. But not sure is it right or any conflict may arise in the future. can anyone suggest how I a  custom sort function as per a given value for the bulk products? Currently, the drag and drop method is difficult in the case of thousand of products.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_bulk_edit_start', 'custom_field_product_bulk_edit', 10, 0 );
function custom_field_product_bulk_edit() {
    ?>
        <div class="inline-edit-group">
            <label class="alignleft">
                <span class="title"><?php _e('Custom Sort Weight', 'woocommerce'); ?></span>
                <span class="input-text-wrap">
                    <select class="change_t_dostawy change_to" name="change_t_dostawy">
                    <?php
                        $options = array(
                            ''  => __( '— No change —', 'woocommerce' ),
                            '1' => __( 'Change to:', 'woocommerce' ),
                        );
                        foreach ( $options as $key => $value ) {
                            echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '">' . $value . '</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                </span>
            </label>
            <label class="change-input">
                <input type="text" name="_t_dostawy" class="text t_dostawy" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Enter Weight Here ', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" value="" />
            </label>
        </div>
    <?php
}

// Save the custom fields data when submitted for product bulk edit
add_action('woocommerce_product_bulk_edit_save', 'save_custom_field_product_bulk_edit', 10, 1);
function save_custom_field_product_bulk_edit( $product ){
    if ( $product->is_type('simple') || $product->is_type('external') ){
        $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['_t_dostawy'] ) ){
           // update_post_meta( $product_id, 'menu_order', sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['_t_dostawy'] ) );
           
            $arg=array('ID' => $product_id,'menu_order' => $_REQUEST['_t_dostawy']);
            $result = wp_update_post($arg);
           
          
           
       }
    }
}
```

I have added an option on quick edit and then update the menu order value by ajax. so that all the product having same menu order will be displayed on same row.But this is not a correct way.

So I have do other stuff that added  text box in the product listing and where we can add a menu order for product.

```
//

 Add product new column in administration
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'woo_product_weight_column', 20 );
function woo_product_weight_column( $columns ) {

    $columns['sort_weight'] = esc_html__( 'Weight', 'woocommerce' );
        return $columns;

}
// Populate weight column
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'woo_product_weight_column_data', 2 );
function woo_product_weight_column_data( $column ) {
    global $post;

    if ( $column == 'sort_weight' ) {
            $postval = get_post( $post->ID);
            $menu_order_new = $postval->menu_order;
            
    ?>
    <input type="text" name="menuorder" id="id_<?php echo $post->ID;?>" data-productid="<?php echo $post->ID;?>" value="<?php  echo $menu_order_new; ?>"  class="menuorder"/>
    <?php     
    }
}


add_action('admin_head', 'my_column_width');

function my_column_width() {
    echo '<style type="text/css">';
    echo 'table.wp-list-table .column-sort_weight { width: 101px; text-align: left!important;padding: 5px;}';
    echo 'table.wp-list-table .column-wpseo-score { width: 101px; text-align: left!important;padding: 5px;}';
    echo'.menuorder{ width: 101px; }';
    echo '</style>';
    
 
   
    
    
}   








// this code adds jQuery script to website footer that allows to send AJAX request
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'misha_jquery_event' );
function misha_jquery_event(){
 
    echo "<script>jQuery(function($){
    var weight_val;
    var pr_id;
        
        
        
         jQuery('.menuorder').on('input', function(){
                weight_val = $(this).val();
                pr_id=$(this).attr('data-productid');
            var dataVariable = {
            'action': 'productmetasave', 
            'product_id': pr_id,
            'value':weight_val
            
                    };

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl, 
            type: 'POST',
            data: dataVariable, 
            success: function (response) {
            if(response==1){
            location.reload(true);
            }else{
                 console.log('Failed To update menu-order ');
            }
               
            }
        });
                
                
                
                
        
        });
    });</script>";
 
}
 
// this small piece of code can process our AJAX request
add_action( 'wp_ajax_productmetasave', 'misha_process_ajax' );
function misha_process_ajax(){
 
    
    if($_POST['product_id'] && $_POST['value'] ){
        
        $arg=array('ID' => $_POST['product_id'],'menu_order' => $_POST['value']);
            $rs = wp_update_post($arg);
            if($rs){
                echo "1";
            }else{
                echo "0";
            }
        }
 
    die();
}
```